# does kibana support max in queries?

Tags: elasticsearch, max, kibana

I am hoping to find some information on the syntax of kibana queries. I want to be able to have a query that returns the max value of a field. Is this possible I have seen some stuff on facets but not sure if it apply's?

I know that max is an option for the histogram but i would like to use it elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Kibana queries use the [Lucene query syntax](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_6_0/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/package-summary.html#package_description) or RegEx, currently its queries seem to return matched records only (no aggregation).

I believe that aggregation (Max, for example) is only possible in Kibana Panels such as the Histogram.